# The error message when trying to login from devise is not showing in a Rails 7.0 application

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a rails 7.0 application, in my `application.html.erb`

```
<body>
<%= yield %>
<div class="signin-container">
  <div class="signin-container-inner">
    <%- flash.each do |name, msg| -%>
      <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <%- end -%>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

When I visit signin page and add some wrong email or password the error message is not showing.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Ruby on Rails 7` uses `:turbo_stream`, we need to make some modifications to get what you need.

First, we let's add a new parent controller for `Devise`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# app/controllers/turbo_devise_controller.rb

class TurboDeviseController < ApplicationController
  class Responder < ActionController::Responder
    def to_turbo_stream
      controller.render(options.merge(formats: :html))
    rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate => e
      if get?
        raise e
      elsif has_errors? && default_action
        render rendering_options.merge(formats: :html, status: :unprocessable_entity)
      else
        redirect_to navigation_location
      end
    end
  end

  self.responder = Responder
  respond_to :html, :turbo_stream
end
```

Second, we also need to tell `Devise` to use our new controller and also add a class to handle our errors:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# app/config/initializers/devise.rb

# ! Create custom failure for turbo
class TurboFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def respond
    if request_format == :turbo_stream
      redirect
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def skip_format?
    %w(html turbo_stream */*).include? request_format.to_s
  end
end

Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.parent_controller = 'TurboDeviseController'
  config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = TurboFailureApp
  end
  ...
end
```

That's it.

More information about it: [GoRails - How to use Devise with Hotwire & Turbo.js](https://gorails.com/episodes/devise-hotwire-turbo?autoplay=1)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround this issue that occurs when using Rails 7, Hotwire, Turbo, and Devise together. By passing `data:{turbo: false}` along with each Devise form, it can prevent Turbo from conflicting with the Devise authentication process. This should allow Devise to function properly while still using Hotwire and Turbo in your Rails application.

Here is an example of how you might use data:{turbo: false} on a Devise form:

```html
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), data: {turbo: false}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
<% end %>
```

In this example, the `data: {turbo: false}` is being passed as an option to the form_for helper method. This tells Turbo to not apply any of its features to this form, which should prevent any conflicts with Devise's authentication process.